# How to compare float numbers in Jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

How could I compare two strings which are actually floating numbers? Something like `"0.1234" < "0.2345"`. Unfortunately, I can't use `float` on the strings since this function does not exist in jinja.

The problem that I try to solve is that I want to present only values above a threshold.

Comment: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#math seems to indicate that division produces float.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use float on the strings, in order to convert them to floating numbers and then compare them. I edited the question appropriately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem by returning a float from the server. Then, comparison works as expected.

Comment: I have the same question as the OP, and this doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Use `{{ var1|float() < var2|float()}}`

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#float